# Google Spreadsheets Script Move Row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Just like you can manually drag a row and it'll rearrange the whole sheet when you release it, I want to be able to do this in a script, such as: sheet.moveRow(from, to);

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `sheets.moveRows(Range, Integer)` method.

See documentation at:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#moveRows(Range,Integer)

There is also the `moveTo()` method which can move either columns or rows.

You'll need to first get a reference to a range, then use the `moveTo()` method of the range.  [Google Documentation - moveTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#moveTo(Range))

This is the sample code from the documentation:

```
// The code below will move the first 5 columns over to the 6th column
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
 sheet.getRange("A1:E").moveTo(sheet.getRange("F1"));
```

Comment: It is worth noting that entire row can be specified by getRange("A1:1")

Comment: @Zotoaster asked how to "move" a row, and not how to "cut and paste" column values

Answer (score 2):

of course you can do what Alan said, but I would use `sheet.moveRows(Range rowSpec, Integer destinationIndex) : void`

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#moverowsrowspec,-destinationindex)